# “Know to speak” vs. “Know how to speak”

Tags: difference

> I **know to speak** English.
>   I **know how to speak** English.

What is the difference between the sentences above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"know to speak" means that you know that you should speak (as opposed to not speaking)

"know how to speak" means that you have the knowledge necessary to speak (you are able to speak).

What you probably intend to say most of the time is:

> I know how to speak English.

This means that you are able to speak English, because you have learned how to speak it.  For example:

> I know how to speak English, so I know what the words mean.

On the other hand,

> I know to speak English.

Means that you know that you should speak English (in some particular situation) instead of speaking some other language.  For example:

> I know to speak English when talking with Bob, because if I don't he won't understand anything I'm saying.